# Print a web page from within R

Tags: r

I can open a web page from within R:

```
shell.exec("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

But how can I then print this webpage, directly from within R, as an xps or pdf file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can invoke a command line tool called [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which is both open source and cross-platform:

```
shell("C:\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf http://stackoverflow.com so.pdf")
```

Do not forget to escape backslashes!

Comment: Good answer.  Pushing a step further: is there a way to save the webpage to pdf AND include the lower part of the screen if you have Firebug running -- or some other tool that shows the HTML code of the webpage?

Comment: @lawyeR No idea. Sounds like it's going to be tricky. I would go with fetching HTML separately and attaching it somehow to the pdf. Not sure if that will be convenient or simple to do so.

Comment: @tonytonov I get `execution failed with error code 1` (even when I copy your code exactly). What does this mean? [I'm using Windows 7 x64 btw]

Comment: @theforestecologist No idea. Do you have wkhtmltopdf installed exactly there? https maybe? Try on other urls, maybe the argument order has changed since then.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old question, but you can use the `webshot` package to do this.

```
# install.packages("webshot")

library(webshot)

webshot("https://stackoverflow.com/", "stackoverflow.pdf")
```