# download.file results in a corrupted pdf

Tags: r

I'm using `download.file` to download a webpage as a pdf

```
download.file("https://thehustle.co/apple-christmas-present", "test.pdf", mode = "wb")
```

This results in the error "The file could not be opened. It may be damaged, or use a file format that Preview doesn't recognise".

SessionInfo:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.16
```

Comment: @Sirius is right, you have to consider the type of file you are downloading and the extension you are giving while saving the file. Have you tried other ways in R to download instead of ```download.file()```? A simple google search will point you to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565748/print-a-web-page-from-within-r

Answer (score 0):

The file you download is an HTML file. (Open it in a text editor and you will see)

Calling it `.pdf` doesn't turn it into a pdf file. Thouhg windows (rather stupidly) thinks it is a pdf file sorely based on the suffix. Don't let it fool you.

Turning a web pageinto a pdf is a completely different matter.